Comments and Changes Missing After Merging GitLab Merge Request
I recently encountered an issue while working with GitLab merge requests (MRs). Here’s the scenario: I reviewed an MR, added comments during the review process, and then merged the MR with those comments. However, after the successful merge, I noticed that the changes were not reflected in the main branch. Additionally, the default setting for MRs was to delete the source branch, but I could still see the branch existed.
Here are the steps I followed:
Review Process:
I reviewed the MR and added comments to address specific issues in the code.
The comments were visible in the MR’s discussion thread.
Successful Merge:
I merged the MR after addressing the comments.
The merge was successful, but the changes were not reflected in the main branch.
Issues Faced:
The comments I had added during the review process were missing after the merge.
The source branch still existed despite the default setting to delete it.
What could be the issue and has some faced the same issue? What would be the fix?
